# In python, what happens when a thread is started inside of a context manager?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-multithreading, contextmanager

As a simple example, take a basic socket:

```
import socket
import threading
import time

def stream(message, socket_):
    while True:
        socket_.sendall(message)
        time.sleep(1)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect((address, port))
    threading.Thread(target=stream, args=("hello world!", sock), daemon=True).start()
```

I assume the flow is something like this:

1. Context is entered, sock is created.
2. The thread is created and stream is called with sock.
3. The context is exited and sock is closed.
4. The stream thread is not using a closed socket and will probably crash.

Is that right? If so, is there any way to continue the context in one or more separate threads?

Comment: The ``socket.socket`` is created within the context manager, and when the context manager is exited (at the end of the with block), it will automatically close the socket. If a thread is still running and using the closed socket, it may indeed lead to issues like "Bad file descriptor" errors or crashes.

Comment: If the thread is created as shown as a daemon, the thread will exit after the `with` exits because the main thread has finished.  Depending on timing, the child thread may error due to the socket being closed by the `with` before the thread is terminated by the main thread exit.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are correct. In the code you provided, the **sock** socket object will be closed when the **with** block is exited. Therefore, if the **stream** thread continues to use the **sock** object after it has been closed, it will raise a **socket.error** or **socket.timeout** exception.

To avoid this issue, you can create the socket outside of the **with** block and pass it as an argument to the **stream** function. This way, the socket will not be closed when the **with** block is exited, and the **stream** function can continue to use it.

To ensure that the socket gets closed when the program exits, you can use the **atexit** module in Python. The **atexit** module provides a way to register functions that will be called when the program is about to exit.

You can register a cleanup function that closes the socket using the **atexit.register()** function. This function takes the cleanup function as an argument and registers it to be called when the program exits.

Here's an updated version of your code that avoids closing the socket prematurely and ensure that the socket gets closed when the program exits:

```py
import socket
import threading
import time
import atexit

def stream(message, socket_):
    while True:
        socket_.sendall(message)
        time.sleep(1)

def cleanup(sock):
    sock.close()

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((address, port))

atexit.register(cleanup, sock)

thread = threading.Thread(target=stream, args=("hello world!", sock), daemon=True)
thread.start()
```

In this code, the **sock** socket object is created outside of the **with** block. Then, the **stream** function is called with the **sock** object as an argument. The context is not exited, so the socket will not be closed prematurely.

Additionally, I have used the **start()** method of the **thread** object to start the thread.

The **cleanup()** function is defined to close the socket. The **atexit.register()** function is used to register the **cleanup()** function with the **sock** object as an argument. This ensures that the **cleanup()** function will be called when the program exits.

Comment: Thanks you for the clear answer. Using this approach, how can we ensure that the socket gets closed when the program exits? In case, for example, an error occurs elsewhere that causes the program to exit, or if the python interpreter is killed?

Comment: To ensure that the socket gets closed when the program exits, you can use the atexit module in Python. The atexit module provides a way to register functions that will be called when the program is about to exit.

You can register a cleanup function that closes the socket using the atexit.register() function. This function takes the cleanup function as an argument and registers it to be called when the program exits.
Check updated code in an answer.

Comment: @PavelNekrasov The socket will be closed when the Python interpreter terminates even without registering any *atexit()* functionality

Comment: @Codist can you link to documentation that states this? Is this something that is handled by the os or is it handled by python?

Comment: One can also just pass the socket to the thread, and close the socket in the thread when it is done with it.  Its use could also be wrapped as `with sock:` in the thread.  Also FYI, when a process exits all open handles are closed and this is handled by the OS.